# 2.8 Issue with data transferring clothing to model's skeleton rig

Tags: mesh, modifiers, rigging, armature

I've been developing a sculpted model for quite some time now and have finally rigged the main body. I haven't gone in to touch up the weight paints yet, and I attempted to data transfer mod some of the clothing to the character. Well it works and it follows the limb's movements but now there's odd face issues on the surface.

[image: Strange tessellations around joints or weight affected areas.]

[image: Ditto.]

I wish to know how to smooth these out so that the clothing better fits the form of the underlying meshes and looks better with deformation.

Comment: Use the smooth tool from weight painting's tool bar on just those verts.  Factor 1.0, source only deselected.

Comment: Thank you, the moment I opened the weight painting for the afflicted areas, i noticed the weights looked like a collage painting. Smoothing them out removed most of the artifacting.